# Need a flag for exact duplicate answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

I often see the some post have similar answers. There is nothing difference in information passed by these answers.

Ok. There is chance to get the number of same answers to post, immediately after posting the question. But some guys make same answer even after seeing it is already exists because the time of span between these answers demands it(around 10 minutes).

Does we need to flag these answers? If so, what should we write to flag?

I have suggestion have a particular dupe flag for answers same as of questions. These answers should be removed from post after couple of days unless a meaningful edit doesn't comes.

Comment: We do already have an [automated duplicate answer checker](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?subtype=duplicateanswer). For now, I'd flag it with "other" and a comment. Make sure to include the duplicate link.

Comment: @nneonneo The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “access to moderator tools”. I don't have the privilege for “access to moderator tools.”

Comment: whoops, yeah, that's for 10k'ers. But that page is just the review queue for the duplicate answer detector. (I can't find the actual dupe detector documented on meta, but it must be here somewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic duplicate answers flagging is for posts of the same poster to different questions.

You are asking for flagging of duplicate answers of different users to the same question.

I think there is no need to flag those answers. Let the community decide by their votes. If they are of equal value, normally the earlier one will get the votes, but **no need to fill the flagging queue**.

But normally, there is some difference in the wording, so the community decide with votes, which one does explain the problem better.

**The other thing is: If there are answers that are really so similar that you think they are duplicates, maybe the question has a problem?**

Often the question is then so easy that it has been answered before, so search for the duplicate question!